# About the implementation of color mixed

Tags: typescript, colors, calculation

Recently I found a method that mix two colors with passing weight and alpha of two colors to get the RGB value. But I don't understand how the calculation of 'w1'.
Could you tell me some implementation details?

```
function mix(
  color1: string,
  color2: string,
  weight: number,
  alpha1?: number,
  alpha2?: number
) {
  color1 = dropPrefix(color1); // remove '#'
  color2 = dropPrefix(color2);
  if (weight === undefined) weight = 0.5;
  if (alpha1 === undefined) alpha1 = 1;
  if (alpha2 === undefined) alpha2 = 1;

  var w = 2 * weight - 1;
  var alphaDelta = alpha1 - alpha2;

  // why?
  var w1 = ((w * alphaDelta === -1 ? w : (w + alphaDelta) / (1 + w * alphaDelta)) + 1) / 2;
  var w2 = 1 - w1;

  // convert to RGB array. 'ffffff' to [255, 255, 255]
  var rgb1 = toNum3(color1);
  var rgb2 = toNum3(color2);
  var r = Math.round(w1 * rgb1[0] + w2 * rgb2[0]);
  var g = Math.round(w1 * rgb1[1] + w2 * rgb2[1]);
  var b = Math.round(w1 * rgb1[2] + w2 * rgb2[2]);
  return '#' + pad2(r) + pad2(g) + pad2(b); // restore to hex string
}
```

Comment: It's normalizing `weight` to a range of 0-1 based on the given alphas. w2 is just the inverse of w1, which is 1 - w1.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to know the normalization process. I don't know how to implement it.